# Which Smash Ultimate characters have additional moves?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

For a while, I thought that every character in Smash Ultimate had precisely the same set of attacks and specials, just different specifics about what those moves did. In other words, I thought this was an exhaustive list of attacks and specials regardless of character:

- 1 or 2 jab attacks
- 3 "tilt" attacks, Up/Side/Down
- 3 "smash" attacks, Up/Side/Down
- 1 "dash" attack
- 5 "air" attacks, Up/Forward/Backward/Down/Neutral
- 4 "special" moves, Up/Side/Down/Neutral

Sometimes those moves would behave differently in situations, but I thought there would always be the same number; for example, when Inkling has no ink, their Neutral and Down special moves are replaced with another move that recovers ink. However, I've recently discovered that the ink-recovery move is actually available at other times as well; it is accessed with Shield+Special while on the ground. I had never previously known that Shield+Special could ever access a move that wasn't in the typical set of 4 specials.

Do any other characters have a "Shield+Special" move which is distinct from their other specials? Or are there any other button combinations which result in an extra attack or special move? Note that this isn't about different results from the same button presses, such as Ganondorf having different "air" down+special and "ground" down+special, only moves which require an actual different combination of inputs.

Comment: There is an ingame control list for every character. As far as I'm aware, every move is listed there.

Comment: @Flater Do you know how to access it? I've never seen it before, but if I can find it and it has the relevant information then I'll make my own answer the next time I have the opportunity.

Comment: When accessed via the in-battle pause menu, it will auto select your character (you = whoever paused the game). There is also an in-main-menu way to do it but I don't know it by heart.

Comment: Hmm this seems a little ambiguous. What about Snake/Piranha Plant forward-tilt which actually has two attacks if you press forward-tilt twice quickly? Or taunts that deal damage and count as "attacks?" What is your criteria for an "Additional Move?"

Comment: @scohe001 My main criteria is "accessed using different inputs than the ones for the attacks in the list". Thus damaging taunts would count, but the double-tilts wouldn't because the second hit is still accessed by another tilt just with specific timing. My *motivation* for asking the question is just that my inability to recover ink effectively gave me a lot of trouble with Inkling, and I want to make sure I'm not missing something similar on other characters. Other users don't have any way to determine "Kamil doesn't know about this" though, so I went with the wording in the question.

Comment: I still don't feel I personally have enough of an understanding to attempt to answer (which category does tapping vs. holding side-B for Samus's two different missiles fall into? What about that same thing for different lengths of Isabelle's fishing rod/Palutena's explosive flame?), but there might be someone else here who has a better idea.

Comment: @scohe001 I consider all of those to *not* be "additional" moves, but I'm beginning to see that "different inputs" is more vague than I intended. If I had not received an answer already, I would probably change the question to exclusively be about the "Shield+Special" combination.

Comment: How about things like Peach/Daisy Float? Holding up doesn't normally doing anything special on any other Character, nor does Holding down then jump (for ground hover). But those attacks don't deal damage and aren't really attacks

Comment: @Malco The main reason I metioned "moves" at all was because I knew some of the things I was looking for don't deal damage; in fact the main one was Inkling ink recovery, which does no damage itself. I haven't thought of a way to refine my "combination of inputs" criteria to be less ambiguous, but on a case-by-case basis I consider those hovers as "part" of jumping rather than an "extra move", similar to Samus's two missile types both being "part" of Side-B.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Hmm, fairly tough to sort out what counts and doesn't but I appreciate you trying and continuing to refine your question. Does greyShift's answer below RE: classic Streetfighter combos on Ryu/Ken count as something you are looking for?

Comment: @Malco The thought I started with was basically that a full description of a character could be broken into short sections where every character would have the same sections. So there would be a "Jump" section, and Peaches would mention "hovering". There would be a "Side-B" section, and Samus's would mention two missile types. Inkling's "Shield-B" didn't fit into any category I could think of, and I wanted to know if there were more exceptions like that.

Comment: @Malco As for the streetfighter specials, I didn't think they counted when I wrote the question because I classified them as "Special + extra thing" and the extra details would just slot in with the respective special's normal description, but based on greyShift's answer it might be more complicated than that.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Not much help for you question, but for your own info you may want to check out the smash wiki and flip through the [character roster for ultimate](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Super_Smash_Bros._Ultimate#Characters) it is long but at least it may help fill gaps you may have

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a number of characters that have additional moves, but first, you are missing a few sets of moves that all characters have:

- 1 Final Smash
- 3 grab moves (regular/pivot/dash, which have the same animation but different frame data)
- 1 pummel (press A while you have a character grabbed)
- 4 throws (up, down, forward, back)
- 3 taunts (up, down, side)
- 2 rolls, a dodge, and a shield drop (forward, back, and down while shielding, and very slight down while on a platform)
- 1 air dodge
- 4 options from ledge (normal getup, attack, jump, roll) (previous games had two of each of these, depending on if you were over 100%, not sure if ultimate has this or not)
- 4 getup options from being knocked down (normal getup, attack, roll left, roll right)
- 3 tech options (tech in place, tech left, tech right)

Here are some other additional moves specific characters get under certain circumstances:

- As mentioned by Mage Xy, Zair moves if you have a tether grab (young link, toon link, samus, dark samus, zero suit samus, lucas, luigi)
- As greyShift has mentioned, Ryu and Ken have different ways of inputting their attacks which grant them more power
- Also as greyShift mentioned, they have "medium" attacks in addition to their tilts and smash attacks
- Bowser Jr has an aerial attack after having used his up B
- Donkey Kong has the option of throwing again after using his Cargo Throw (forward throw)
- Robin has different aerial attacks when you smash the control stick rather than tilt it, as with smash attacks vs tilts on the ground. The levin sword must be available to perform these.
- As you mentioned, Inkling has the special option of pressing B while shielding
- Samus and Dark Samus have two different side-Bs, depending on if you smash the control stick or not. Smash side-B produces a super-missile as opposed to a regular missile.

And for completeness, here is a list of the characters whose moves are actually completely separate moves, however they simply replace other moves:

- Kirby has 78(?) different neutral Bs, depending on who he has eaten
- Little Mac has a different neutral B depending on if his KO Punch is charged
- Cloud has a different Down B according to whether or not his Limit Break is charged. Also all his specials are different once Limit Break has been charged.
- Ken and Ryu both have two final smashes, depending on where the opponent is located
- Worth mentioning that technically Pokemon Trainer is one character, so all moves are duplicated three times between Squirtle, Ivysaur and Charizard.
- The Miis each have 4 options for each special

Comment: Sorry, just getting the answer out there first, Little Mac's "power" should really be specified as his KO Punch. I have edited that in. As far as I know, there is only one air dodge move, but pressing a direction moves you in that direction - there are far more than just 9 directions you can go. It uses the analog stick and is however precise you want to be. I'll fix the Robin one too

Comment: if you include little mac KO punch, Cloud limit moves should also be included, and maybe neutral B charge moves

Comment: Ah Cloud! I know I'm still missing a few. Thanks. I thought about charge moves like Samus Charge Beam but I think the OP would consider those one move, as he knows about the separate attacks as part of a jab.

Comment: Would love for down-voters to explain their downvotes...

Comment: You might want Marth and friends side-B variants too

Comment: Oh good call! both of those

Comment: Hmm... Actually although all those side-B variants require special input, they are still really the same move, akin to jabs I think

Comment: Hey, don't forget that there are now 9 airdodges w/ different frame data ;)

Comment: @scohe001 actually I was right the first time about Robin, I have updated to include that detail

Comment: You might also mention "chained" attacks (not sure what the community calls them) where hitting certain buttons with certain timing changes the attacks.  e.g. B after Incineroar's side-B, A after Link's side smash, B after Duck Hunt's B/side-B, etc.

Comment: Also if we are going for maximum detail, another interesting category is attacks that can be controlled with directional input, e.g. Zelda's side-B, Ness/Lucas's B/up-B, Inkling's B, etc.

Comment: After Kirby inhales, he can release his copy ability by taunting.  This is a status move, similar to Inkling's ink tank charge.

Answer (score 10):

Ryu and Ken have additional attacks used by inputting their Street Fighter inputs.
Both characters have a stronger Shoryuken(up-B) they can do by pressing forward, down, downforward, then A or B.  This does 1.25x damage and has some additional properties.
They also both have the Hadouken (neutral B) input, which is down, downforward, forward, then A or B.  Ryu can also do a multi-hitting red fireball with back, downback, down, downforward, forward, then A or B.
There is also Tatsumaki (side-B) for both characters using quarter-circle back, and Ken has at least one more input for an overhead kick which I think is quarter-circle down.  I'll link a guide later for the full list of special inputs.

They also both have access to strong and light tilts.  If you press utilt and release the button quickly, it will be a quick, soft, and spammable elbow that easily confirms into shoryuken.  If you press utilt and hold the button, it is a slower strong elbow that has invulnerability on his upper body.  All of the tilts and jab have this light/heavy option.

I'd also like to mention that Marth/Lucina/Roy/Chrom can change hits 2,3, and 4 of side-B by inputting up, down, or neutral during each input.

Answer (score 4):

Inkling is the only character that has a separate Shield-Special ability. This is because it would be too punishing to play Inkling without a way to recharge their ink outside of depleting their reserves first.

There are a few characters that also have a unique "Air Grab" attack. The attack doesn't actually grab, it basically acts like any other aerial attack, though with slightly longer range. You can use this attack by pressing the grab button while in the air.

These characters that can use an air grab are the ones that use a tether of some kind when they grab normally:

- Young Link and Toon Link shoot out their hookshot
- Luigi shoots plunger from his vacuum
- Samus and Dark Samus shoot out their grapple beam
- Zero Suit Samus shoots out a plasma whip
- Lucas throws out his pet snake

Other than that, no other characters have extra attacks.

Comment: In the Smash community, we usually call forward/back/neutral/down air, fair/bair/nair/dair. This "Air Grab" is referred to as a ["zair,"](https://www.ssbwiki.com/grab_aerial) since the default grab button is z. (only noting this since it took me reading your examples to realize what you meant by "Air Grab")

Comment: @scohe001 Unfortunately I'm not a card carrying member of the Smash community, I just crash their parties sometimes. (I'm teasing, haha) That's a good note, thanks!

Comment: You should be careful then, I’ve heard secondhand Smash can be worse than playing Smash yourself! :P I didn’t mean to make it sound so cliquey though, sorry about that. Only meant that commentators at tournaments and stuff will use that terminology.

Comment: Also note that some of these moves have utility beyond damage-at-range as they can allow you to grab a ledge from quite some distance

Comment: Also you forgot about poor [Lucas](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Lucas_(SSBU)) and his friendly snake

Comment: @Seiyria Simon and Richter's "tethers" are actually their normal aerial attacks. Their regular grab is melee range and they do not possess a ZAir attack.

Comment: @Harabeck If I understand OP correctly, they are not that interested in regular moves that simply have an optional second (or third, or etc.) part, but more along the line of moves that require button combinations that don't do anything on most other characters.